# SharePoint Tweaking UI Fields using DOM Explorer/FireBug

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have SharePoint 2010 application with contains Custom Web Parts. A single web part usually contain around 200 UI fields. Some of them are enabled and few are disabled with default values that will be loaded based on the logged in user.

Recently we came across an issue, user while submitting the application can use FireBug/DOM Explorer or some other developer tool and can tweak the disabled fields which finally submits the wrong values to the database.

We are trying to use Session Variables to store these default values and while storing them to database taking these values from Session instead of taking them from UI form.

Please let me know whether there is any better way to prevent such hacks in SharePoint?

Comment: So for example if you have choice field in your web part then user can add value not from the list to input field using developer tools? I think that you should check input values on server for validity.